# Where can I find AndroidViewClient documentation?

Tags: automated-tests, androidviewclient

Is there any documentation on AndroidViewClient covering public classes, methods, and syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the [doc](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/tree/master/doc) directory of the project.

You have to *clone* or *download* the project to view it properly in your browser as github's web interface will show the source code instead.

## UPDATE

[jthurner](https://github.com/jthurner) found a way, I didn't know existed, of showing the *docs* over github pages. You can now view the documentation online at **[API Documentation](https://dtmilano.github.io/AndroidViewClient/)**.